# reddit comment system how to replicate in mongodb/nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I make nested comment replies in MongoDB/mongoose to create a comment system like in reddit nesting. Here are my schemas i created so far:

```
var CommentSchema = Schema({
    body: {type: String},
    chapterId: {type: RK, ref: 'Chapter'},
    by: {type: RK, ref: 'User'},
}, {timestamps: true});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: {type:String, unique: true},
    profile_pic: String,
  password: String,
  role:{type: [{
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin']
    }],
    default: ['user']
}
});
```